# Aplicar filtro em uma lista retornada por um mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testes, testes-de-unidade, mock

Boa noite!
Eu tenho o seguinte cenário:

Uma classe concreta chamada UsuarioServico, que recebe por injeção de dependências o repositório através de uma interface e um notificador. Ela fica assim

```
private readonly IUsuarioRepository _repository;

    public UsuarioService(INotificator notificador, IUsuarioRepository repository) : base(notificador, repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

Dentro desse serviço eu tenho um método chamado BuscarOperacoesUsuario(Guid idUsuario), esse método apenas chama um método do repositório com o mesmo nome. No repositório é onde fica a lógica dessa query.

O que acontece é que quando eu crio um mock do meu UsuarioService, e configuro no setup o que eu espero retornar do método BuscarOperacoesUsuario, passando uma lista de operações ele não aplica o filtro de ID de usuário que está lá no repositório.

Aqui o método do meu serviço

```
public async Task<List<Operacao>> BuscarOperacoesUsuario(Guid idUsuario)
    {
        return await _repository.BuscarOperacoesUsuario(idUsuario);
    }
```

Aqui o método no meu repositório

```
public async Task<List<Operacao>> BuscarOperacoesUsuario(Guid idUsuario)
    {
        return await Db.Operacoes.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(operacao => operacao.UsuariosOperacoes)
            .Where(operacao => operacao.UsuariosOperacoes.Any(uo => uo.IdUsuario == idUsuario))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Aqui a criação do mock e o setup do metodo

```
 var mocker = new AutoMocker();
 var usuarioService = mocker.CreateInstance<UsuarioService>();
mocker.GetMock<IUsuarioRepository>().Setup(c => c.BuscarOperacoesUsuario(It.IsAny<Guid>   ())).ReturnsAsync(operacoes);
```

No caso ali em operações é uma lista com 4 itens, sendo que 2 deles tem o mesmo ID de usuário, porém o método sempre retorna 4 itens e não apenas os 2 do usuário que estou passando na chamada do mock

```
            var resultado = await usuarioService.BuscarOperacoesUsuario(usuarioValido.Id);
```

OBS: Eu alterei o metodo do meu serviço para retornar uma lista sem aplicar o filtro, guardei essa lista em uma variável e depois eu apliquei o filtro e então funcionou... mas assim eu teria que sempre retornar TUDO do banco e aplicar o filtro em memória e não vai ficar legal.

UsuarioService assim ele aplica o WHERE na minha lista.

```
  public async Task<List<Operacao>> BuscarOperacoesUsuario(Guid idUsuario)
    {
        var teste = await _repository.BuscarOperacoesUsuario(idUsuario);
        return teste.Where(operacao => operacao.UsuariosOperacoes.Any(uo => uo.IdUsuario == idUsuario)).ToList();
    }
```

Repository

```
 public async Task<List<Operacao>> BuscarOperacoesUsuario(Guid idUsuario)
    {
        return await Db.Operacoes.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(operacao => operacao.UsuariosOperacoes)
            //.Where(operacao => operacao.UsuariosOperacoes.Any(uo => uo.IdUsuario == idUsuario))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método que você faz mock não tem nenhuma lógica, ele simplesmente retorna uma lista.

Você deveria fazer algo assim:

```cs
mocker.GetMock<IUsuarioRepository>()
   .Setup(c => c.BuscarOperacoesUsuario(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
   .ReturnsAsync((Guid usuarioId) => 
      operacoes.Where(op => 
         op.UsuariosOperacoes.Any(uo => uo.IdUsuario == usuarioId)));
```

Comment: eu cheguei a fazer assim mas ai se o meu filtro mudar lá no repositório o meu teste vai continuar passando né ? Eu tentei mockar o repositório pq é ele que implementa o método mas nao consegui por conta do db context que preciso passar pra classe base

Comment: @RafaelScheffer Acho que você tá confundindo as coisas. Se você está testando o serviço, precisa considerar que o repositório vai estar certo...

Comment: aaaaa acho que saquei, comecei a estudar testes unitários agora, na realidade eu vou ter que ter outro teste só pra repositório, beleza, beleza muito obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelScheffer Isso. Você vai testar cada classe de forma isolada.